Unable to get Metric Kit logs on iOS devices for past 24 hours on Test Flight Build
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metrickit
I am unable to get the MetricKit logs for past 24 hours time period on my test flight build. I have been able to achieve immediate logs for crash, cpu exception and diskwrite exceptions. But the logs which contains all the crashes, cpu exceptions and diskwrite exceptions, battery and network details, etc for the previous day are never generated.
I have used the method to log the payloads in the file systems.
func didReceive(_ payloads: [MXDiagnosticPayload])

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metrickit/mxmetricmanagersubscriber/didreceive(_:)-9yd4u

I suggest generating some of your own metrics and then see if it reports them back to yourself via the callback.  There is a YouTube video on that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7aPR4c9qLXs. Then you can see if it Apple-side generation issue or not.

In some cases, TestFlight builds don't send all MetricKit data as expected, especially for longer periods. Ensure that you are testing on a release build and not a debug or ad-hoc build for the best chance of receiving the complete metrics.
